# How to change sub-bullet points font size in Rpres?

Tags: css, r, rstudio, rpres

I am using R presentations to create talk slides. I am trying to have bullet points at different sizes, so the the sub-bullet points (blah2) are smaller than the main ones (blah).

I know that style can be amended using a CSS stylesheet, which can be put inline before the slides code. I've modified it but it's not giving me the desired results:

```
Presentation Title
========================================================
author: 
date: 20/03/18

<style>
.reveal ul, 
.reveal ol {
    font-size: 40px;
}

.reveal ol p{
font-size: 20px;
}
</style> 

Slide 1
========================================================

- blah
    - blah2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just fought this battle and FML it's painful.

I ended up doing this in my css:

```
/* body text, ordered and unordered list styles */
.reveal ul, 
.reveal ol, 
.reveal p{
    font-size: 180%;
    line-height: 110%;
    list-style-type: disc;
}

/* slide titles */
.reveal h3 { 
  font-size: 200%;
}
/* heading for slides with two hashes ## */
.reveal .slides section .slideContent h2 {
   font-size: 40px;
   font-weight: bold;
   color: green;
}
```

Notice that I have the list bits and p all lumped together. I want them always to change at the same time so I assign them all at once.